CORS Issue When Deploying Travel Web Application on EC2 and Using Ngrok
We are developing a travel web application and attempting to deploy it on an EC2 instance. We've also tried using ngrok for tunneling, but we're encountering persistent CORS issues between different origins. Despite trying various plugins, the CORS error continues to appear. How can we resolve this issue?
We tried using cors everywhere plugin(firefox).
Tried this code snippet as well
 app.get('/cors', (req, res) => {
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
res.send({ "msg": "This has CORS enabled " })
}) 
{
"proxy":"http://localhost:8080";
}``
The error we are facing is :
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/login' from origin '*' has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space local.Understand this error
localhost:8080/login:1
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

This question is not reproducible and needs more debugging information. Why do you use localhost on your EC2 deployment version?

I’ve given localhost, since express is accessible on localhost in the ec2 instance
Tried updating the public ip of ec2 instance
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({
origin:"http://37.92.22.102:8080"
}));

Added proxy in frontend package.json to bypass the CORS
{
...
"proxy":"http://localhost:8080"
}

1.Tried cors anywhere (firefox ) & cors unblock (Chrome) plugin in the browser.
2. Tried running the chrome browser without web-security .
  google-chrome --disable-web-security--user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev"


Tried allowing origin in app.js
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express(); // Allow all origins for now app.use(cors());

Tried adding Custom CORS headers
app.use((req, res, next) => {
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8080'); // Adjust if needed
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
next();
});

Tried updating CORS middleware options
const corsOptions = { origin: '', methods: 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS', allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type, Authorization', credentials: true }; app.use(cors(corsOptions)); app.options('', cors(corsOptions)); // Handle preflight requests

Tried updating the Origin:
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({
origin:"http://localhost:3000"
}));

Tried adding Access control allow origin:
app.get('/cors', (req, res) => {
res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
res.send({ "msg": "This has CORS enabled " })
})
